# In Java, How to draw multi-line text with auto-resizing font that must fit into a bounds

Tags: java, text, draw

Using TextLayout and LineMeasurer (The only way to draw multiline center-aligned text in java), How does one go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a JTextPane. You can set the paragraph attributes to "centered" and every line will be centered within the text pane. After you create the text pane you can do something like:

```
SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
```

Comment: How can the JTextPane be made to be to be transparent in such a way that only the drawn text shows? It needs to look just like a normal graphics.drawString(...)

Comment: It is a normal graphics string. Play with the background, foreground, opaque methods to achieve what you want. I don't know if you are trying to mimic custom painting on a JPanel or for a JLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Hey camickr, I don't think this solution properly handles the auto-resizing of fonts to fit within bounds.
I am essentially drawing text to a JScreen (Windowless form of a Jframe) for text projection reasons, and I need whatever text that is in there to conform to the bounds of the screen, no matter what font size was initially set, so it auto-adjusts font size as neccessary.

Center alignment really isn't the problem here. I can do center aligned on my own without the JTextPane. The problem is the font fitting within bounds.

I didn't want to have to loop through and check textlayout bounds each time after a get from linemeasurer and minimize font size till it's just right, but it seems would be the only way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

So I created a wrapper class around LineBreakMeasurer, which immediately populates an arraylist of TextLayouts upon instantiation of the wrapper class. While generating this array list of layouts, I got the lineheight of each layout and added that incrementally to a total line height. I can then externally query this wrapper for the total lineheight of all it's text and if it is greater than my vertical bounds, I rederive the font with a lesser font size and repopulate the arraylist of layouts....which can then be gotten from the arraylist using some getNextLayout() method.

I also had this wrapper class force '\n' to be respected by lineBreakMeasurer by doing a String [] lines = text.split("\n")
And then running linebreakMeasurer on each of those lines as I populated the arraylist of layouts.